# (iPad Dev)Is there a way to deselect the first scope button in a scope bar of a search bar?

Tags: button, scope, uisearchbar

The first scope button in a scope bar of a search bar is always selected when the scope bar is appeared.
Is there a way to deselect the button when it appears? (I want to do is deselect all the buttons)

Comment: for (id view in [searchBar subviews]) {
  if ([view isMemberOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]) {
   UISegmentedControl *scopeBar = (UISegmentedControl*)view;
   scopeBar.selectedSegmentIndex = -1;
  }
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (id view in [searchBar subviews]) 
{ 
    if ([view isMemberOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]) 
    { 
        UISegmentedControl scopeBar = (UISegmentedControl)view;
        scopeBar.selectedSegmentIndex = -1; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just set `selectedScopeButtonIndex` property of `UISearchBar` to `-1`.